# Exporting VOB Subtitles in ffmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, dvd, subtitles

Hey I've been trying to figure out a way to export image based subtitles from MKVs which have been ripped from BluRays or DVDs.

The streams are there and can be hard-coded to the video, but I was wondering if anyone knew how to export them to an SRT/ASS/SSA or anything else I could work with and OCR.

I've looked through some similar questions and have not found an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: there is an ocr filter, but I almost doubt its plumbed to work well with DVD's yet...

Answer (score 1):

You'll have better luck with mkvextract, part of the [mkvtoolnix](https://www.bunkus.org/videotools/mkvtoolnix/) package.

For Bluray subs :

```
$ mkvextract tracks input.mkv 2:subtitles.sup
```

Or for DVDs :

```
$ mkvextract tracks input.mkv 2:subtitles.sub
```

Please note that you may have to change that '2' to the subtitles track ID you want. I just assumed you only had one video and one audio track before the subtitle track, which ID would then be '2'.

You can then OCR them with [SubtitleEdit](https://github.com/SubtitleEdit/subtitleedit/releases) to obtain .srt files.